# Repairing Windows Bootloader for gpt use

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, bootloader, gpt

I bought i new `hard disk with 3 tb of space` where i wanted to install 3 different OS(1 Windows and 2 Linux). Since i had a `3 tb hard disk` i needed to use `gpt` which made it not possible for me to get the `Windows` OS working. Here is what i did trying to make it work:

At first i installed `Windows` which means that have the `msdos partition table` which makes `Windows` `bootable` but doesn't allow the two other Linux OS to install. Since i don't have a `UEFI-Mainboard` i cant install `Windows` with `gpt` directly.

So I changed to `msdos partition table` to `gpt` with `gdisk` and the `Linux Mint Live-CD` which of course destroyed the `windows bootloader`.

The error message I get when trying to load `Windows` tells me to fix `Windows` with the `Recovery-CD` which is not possible because there I get the `error message: not compatible version...` because of the use of `gpt`, so i can't fix it with the CD.

But i can access my `Window partition` through my other `Linux OS's`, so maybe there is a possibility to install a new Bootloader via `wine` or to repair the old one.

> Question: How can I fix my Bootloader problem without UEFI and without the Recovery CD or how can I install Windows with gpt without UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

> Since i had a 3 tb hard disk i needed to use gpt

MBR will work fine up to 16Tb (tera bit, or 2TiB, tera Byte) with 512 bytes sized sectors.

> which made it not possible for me to get the Windows OS working. Here is what i did trying to make it work:
>
> first I installed Windows which means that have the msdos partition
> table

Uhm sometimes yes, sometimes no. If you have an old motherboard with BIOS firmware then yes, it will install in the old mode and it will use and MBR partition table.

If you have a modern computer it will not have BIOS firmware but it will have EFI firmware. Any modern windows (from win7 x64 and up) will use GPT when you boot in EFI mode.

So you:

- Either have an old computer (8+ ish years old) and it is very likely to have a problem with a large disk,
- or you have a motherboard with [U]EFI firmware but explicitly enabled backward compatabily shims.

> Since i don't have a UEFI-Mainboard i cant install Windows with gpt
> directly.

ON an old board you either:

- Install a small disk to boot from. (HDD or SSD is typical, but you may be able to use a CDROM or an USB based pendrive).
- Get lucky and have a rare board with a good BIOS firmware which recognises GPT and protective MBR. (That is, both MBR and GPT, and the MBR entry is a fake to claim the whole disk).

> So I changed to msdos partition table to gpt with gdisk and the Linux Mint
> Live-CD which of course destroyed the windows bootloader.

MBR uses a bootsector and then the ntloader. GPT works completely different. If you want windows to work with GPT you will need to install if while booting in UEFI mode. It will write the nessecary files (e.g. bootX86.EFI) to the EFI system partition. Just changing the disk layout and/or the bootloader is not enough.

> But i can access my Window partition through my other Linux OS's, so maybe
> there is a possibility to install a new Bootloader via wine or to repair
> the old one.
>
> Question: How can I fix my Bootloader problem without UEFI and without the
> Recovery CD or how can I install Windows with gpt without UEFI?

You cannot. You only have a few options, which include:

1. A seperate small MBR formatted boot disk (HDD/SSD) for the windows install (a 16GiB eSATA pendrive or similar will work perfectlyu for this).
2. Or only run Linux and from within Linux run a virtual windows (e.g. use something like vmware player).
3. Or directly run a type-1 hypervisor. (e.g. Xen).